# Update objects in a list from another List

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist, merge

I have a user list

```
List<User> usrList1 = new ArrayList<User>();
userList.add(new User("usr1",11,""));
userList.add(new User("usr2",22,""));
userList.add(new User("usr3",33,""));
```

another User List contains

```
List<User> usrList2 = new ArrayList<User>();
userList2.add(new User("",11,"add1"));
userList2.add(new User("",22,"add2"));
```

now how can I merge these two List and get a single list of User using **id**, considering **performance**. Consider the size of `userList1` and `userList2` are around 50.

```
List<User> usrList = new ArrayList<User>();
userList.add(new User("usr1",11,"add1"));
userList.add(new User("usr2",22,"add2"));
userList.add(new User("usr3",33,""));
```

Comment: Where does "add3" come from in the final list?

Comment: sry my bad. updated.

Comment: Performance is really out of question here, for lists of 50 items.

Comment: Why not try to use Map? You can easily update every usrList1 with elements of usrList2, just putting the new value.

Comment: @Molinetas object in usrList1 has few values(like name) and usrList2 has few other values(like address) only id is common among them. I didn't get you how to use map in this scenario.

Comment: @gauti I was thinking in using a Map to use a Collections library that may do the merge for you. The Map allows to "update" values with the same id.

Comment: If you are very sure of getting out this scenario using map, please post the solution as answer. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward for a small list, without considering performance issues and assuming a merge strategy of appending `Name` and `Data` fields:

- Copy (shallow) `list1` into a new list `merged`
- Iterate over `list2`

  - For each item in `merged` check if item in `list2` already exists
  - If the item exists, just update its fields
  - If it does not exist, append it to the end of `merged`

Code:

```
public static List<User> Merge(List<User> list1, List<User> list2) {
    List<User> merged = new ArrayList<User>(list1);
    for (User user : list2) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (User u : merged) {
            if (u.Id == user.Id) {
                found = true;
                u.Name += user.Name;
                u.Data += user.Data;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            merged.add(user);
        }
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user HashMap as helper data structure
For key is needed to use user id (integer value in list)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> userList1 = new ArrayList<User>();
    userList1.add(new User("usr1", 11, ""));
    userList1.add(new User("usr2", 22, ""));
    userList1.add(new User("usr3", 33, ""));

    List<User> userList2 = new ArrayList<User>();
    userList2.add(new User("", 11, "add1"));
    userList2.add(new User("", 22, "add2"));

    // Insert all elements from first list to hash map
    HashMap<Integer, User> userMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (User user : userList1) {
        userMap.put(user.getId(), user);
    }

    // Update user elements
    for (User user : userList2) {
        User update = userMap.get(user.getId());
        update.setAddres(user.getAddress());
    }

    // convert hash map to list
    List<User> merge = new ArrayList<>();
    merge.addAll(userMap.values());

    System.out.println(merge);
}
```

**Note**: 
HashMap will not preserve the order of elements. If it is needed to `merge` list be in the same order as `userList1` then use LinkedHashMap.

Comment: I was trying to avoid multiple collection objects and multiple for loop . Anyways thanks for you answer.